# The EF Core child entity isn't loaded along with the parent

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, querying

## The database

I'm working on a SQL Server database with two tables: `INVOICE_HEADER` and `INVOICE_ROW`.
`INVOICE_HEADER` has two fields:

- `INTERNAL_ID`, type `int` and the primary key,
- `INV_NUM`, type `varchar(13)`, which is unique per business logic but not per database structure.

`INVOICE_ROW` has three:

- `INTERNAL_ID`, type `int` and the primary key,
- `INV_NUM`, type `varchar(13)`,
- `INV_ROW_NUM`, type `int`, unique per business logic as well.

Rows from `INVOICE_ROW` with the same value for `INV_NUM` as a row from `INVOICE_HEADER` make up the same invoice in business logic terms, so `INVOICE_HEADER.INV_NUM` and (`INVOICE_ROW.INV_Num`, `INVOICE_ROW.INV_ROW_NUM`) serve as de facto primary keys as far as our queries are concerned.

The values found in `INVOICE_HEADER.INTERNAL_ID` are different from those found in `INVOICE_ROW.INTERNAL_ID`, and no field in either table seems to have a value corresponding to that of `INTERNAL_ID` in the other.

So there is no actual foreign key linking either table to the other.

Do I need to mention the database comes from a third party, its structure is fixed, it has many more tables, and that both `INVOICE_HEADER` and `INVOICE_ROW` have many more fields? Well at any rate I just did.

Actually, `INTERNAL_ID` hardly even shows up in the document describing the database structure, field by field, and only for a few other tables.

## Using Entity Framework Core to access the database

I can't use the primary keys defined in the database for the aforementioned reasons.

So I've created two classes:

```
    public class InvoiceHeader
    {
        public int InternalId { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceNum { get; set; }

        public virtual List<InvoiceRow> InvoiceRows { get; set; }
    }

    public class InvoiceRow
    {
        public int InternalId { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceNum { get; set; }
        public int? RowNum { get; set; }

        public virtual InvoiceHeader InvHeader { get; set; }
    }
```

And a context:

```
        public DbSet<InvoiceHeader> RepoInvHeader { get; set; }
        public DbSet<InvoiceRow> RepoInvRow { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder p_mbuModel)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(p_mbuModel);

            // Table name
            p_mbuModel.Entity<InvoiceHeader>().ToTable("INVOICE_HEADER");

            // Primary key
            p_mbuModel.Entity<InvoiceHeader>().HasKey(t => new { t.InternalId }).
                                               HasName("PK_INTERNAL_ID_INVOICE_HEADER");

            // Fields
            p_mbuModel.Entity<InvoiceHeader>().Property(t => t.InternalId).IsRequired();
            p_mbuModel.Entity<InvoiceHeader>().Property(t => t.InternalId).HasColumnType("int");
            p_mbuModel.Entity<InvoiceHeader>().Property(t => t.InvoiceNum).HasColumnName("INV_NUM");
            p_mbuModel.Entity<InvoiceHeader>().Property(t => t.InvoiceNum).HasColumnType("varchar(13)");
            p_mbuModel.Entity<InvoiceHeader>().Property(t => t.InvoiceNum).HasMaxLength(13);

            // Foreign keys
            p_mbuModel.Entity<InvoiceHeader>().HasMany(h => h.InvoiceRows).
                                               WithOne(r => r.InvHeader).
                                               HasPrincipalKey(h => h.InvoiceNum).
                                               HasForeignKey(r => r.InvoiceNum);

            // Table name
            p_mbuModel.Entity<InvoiceRow>().ToTable("INVOICE_ROW");

            // Primary key
            p_mbuModel.Entity<InvoiceRow>().HasKey(t => new { t.InternalId }).
                                            HasName("PK_INTERNAL_ID_INVOICE_ROW");

            // Fields
            p_mbuModel.Entity<InvoiceRow>().Property(t => t.InternalId).IsRequired();
            p_mbuModel.Entity<InvoiceRow>().Property(t => t.InternalId).HasColumnType("int");
            p_mbuModel.Entity<InvoiceRow>().Property(t => t.InvoiceNum).HasColumnName("INV_NUM");
            p_mbuModel.Entity<InvoiceRow>().Property(t => t.InvoiceNum).HasColumnType("varchar(13)");
            p_mbuModel.Entity<InvoiceRow>().Property(t => t.RowNum).HasColumnName("INV_ROW_NUM");
            p_mbuModel.Entity<InvoiceRow>().Property(t => t.RowNum).HasColumnType("int");

            // Foreign keys
            p_mbuModel.Entity<InvoiceRow>().HasOne(r => r.InvHeader).
                                            WithMany(h => h.InvoiceRows).
                                            HasForeignKey(r => r.InvoiceNum).
                                            HasPrincipalKey(h => h.InvoiceNum);
        }
```

I feel all those mentions with `HasMany`, `WithOne` are necessary to make up for the lack of a true, usable primary key.

## The results

I tried the following:

```
            InvoiceHeader z_objHeader = z_dbcContexteSage.repoInvHeader.Include(h => h.InvoiceRows).FirstOrDefault(h => h.Piece == "XXXX");
```

On debugging, `z_objHeader` duly has the values I'd expect for the fields from `INVOICE_HEADER`, but its `InvoiceRows` property is `null`. (I also tried `foreach (InvoiceRow z_objRow in z_objHeader.InvoiceRows)`: it throws a `NullReferenceException`.)

Now, if I add this and run it as well,

```
            InvoiceRow z_objRow = z_dbcContexteSage.repoInvRow.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Piece == "XXXX");
```

looking at `z_objHeader.InvoiceRows` shows that it now contains **one** `InvoiceRow`.

Even better, after running

```
            List<InvoiceRow> z_lisRows = z_dbcContexteSage.repoInvRow.Where(r => r.Piece == "XXXX").ToList();
```

`z_objHeader.InvoiceRows` now has **all** the rows I'd expect it to have.

So I can work with that, but I still feel that those commands explicitly loading from `INVOICE_ROW` shouldn't be needed, or even useful.

I've looked far and wide on the Web and I can't seem to find out what I've overlooked or left out.

I guess the catch might be with that official-but-unusable-primary-key/de-facto-primary-key stuff.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you read the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/

Comment: I think you should look into alternate keys. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: @jeroenh: I did, thanks! On your prompting, I looked again and saw that maybe split queries could hold the answer, but the documentation says they will be available with version 5.0 (interestingly stating that in the present tense whereas I updated EF Core yesterday and it's still 3.1.9).

Comment: @jeroenh: I tried to use `AsSplitQuery()` before understanding that it wouldn't compile because it isn't available yet. It led me to notice and comment a `using System.Data.Entity;` . Now that it's done -- guess what -- `InvoiceRows` is correctly loaded! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't something I had forgotten to put in, it was something I (or someone else) had put in at some point.

There was a

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

in the testing class, that was apparently messing the `Update()` method. Now that it's gone, the property `InvoiceRows` is correctly loaded.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to read the question!